# Probability that n real estate units will become vacant in the same month

Tags: probability

So I have a problem I'm working on for a presentation to some clients, and I'm hoping someone can help me with it.

Let's say I have a rental property with X number of units. I need to figure out the probability that all X units become vacant in the same month. It does not matter which month it happens.

Parameters:

- <strike>There is also the possibility that the unit won't be vacant at all during that period (so the number of permutations for each unit is 13)</strike>
- Let's say for simplicity's sake that each unit will be vacant once during the 12 month period.
- The vacancies all have to occur in the exact same month, so of all possible permutations, there are only ever acceptable combinations (which I believe is represented by 12/x, where x is the total number of permutations).

I'm sure this is simpler than I'm making it out to be, but I can't remember which techniques to use, it's been a long time since I've had to do this kind of math.

---

I'm also going to state the problem a different way, and see if it helps.

I have a string of characters: ABCDEFGHIJKL

- each letter represent the unit being vacant in a single month of the year from Jan - Dec

Using these characters, you can make a string of any length, for example:

- A
- AJ
- ABA
- AABC
- ACBAGIJ
  ...etc

for each iteration, the only acceptable results are strings where the letters are identical. Example:

- AA
- KKK
- JJJJJJJJ

---

NOTE: Several people have stated that the answer is:
$$ \left( \frac{1}{12} \right)^{X-1}$$

However, I believe that answer is incorrect. The probability that a single unit will be vacant in the first year is 100%, not 0%. This formula says that the probability 2 units will be vacant at the same time is 8.3%. But given the following legend:
[image: legend]

the first year probability actually looks like this: (remember, unit order does not matter) [image: first year probability], where the items in bold are the results we're looking for. In this case, there are 12+11+10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1=78 results, and only 12 are actually possible. This means the probability is 12/78, which is 15.3%.

As you add units, the complexity increases exponentially, but you still only get 12 possible results.

Thanks!
-Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With four lots, the number of different possibilities for when those lots are empty is 12^4=20736. Of those, 12 have them all on the some month (one for each particular month). Therefore the probability of them all being empty on the same month is 12/12^4=1/12^3=1/1728. In general, if you have m lots, the probability of them all being empty on the same month is 1/12^(m-1).

Comment: Please see my edits for additional feedback.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. That isn't how it works, because (this is from your example from your edit) AB is twice as likely as AA, because AB actually has 2 ways it could happen (AB or BA). Therefore the answer was correct, and the probability is 1/1728. Unit order may not matter, but that does not change the fact that it is twice as likely.

Comment: Let me give you a smaller example. Assume there are only two options (A and B), and two lots. There are two ways they could be the same (AA and BB). The probability is 2/4=1/2, not 2/3 that they are the same. If you don't believe me, test this with flipping two coins (about 20 times will do).

Comment: OK, I think you're right. I was thinking of permutations, but regardless of the permutation, the probability is the same.

Comment: BTW, this explanation made more sense to me, because 12/12^m shows what is happening better than the simplified formula. Thanks everyone for your help! :)

Comment: I'm happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

In some sense, there's only one month you need to consider, the month that any one of the apartments is vacant.

More precisely, pick any apartment. Say it's vacant in June. Then you want to know the probability that all the *other* apartments are vacant in June, which happens with probability 
$$ \left( \frac{1}{12} \right)^{X-1}$$

Of course the same  logic holds whatever month the first one was vacant on, so this is your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your work. Please see my edits for additional feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have $4$ units namely $A, B, C, D$ in an apartment.

For any given month, each unit can either be occupied or vacant.

So you have two choices for $A$, two choices for $B$, two choices for $C$ and two choices for $D$.

So there are $2^{4}=16$ possible 'looks' the apartment can have.

And only one of those 'looks' has all the unit vacant.

In general if you have $X$ units you can have $2^{X}$ possible 'looks' in a given month. Only one of which all the units are vacant.

So the probability is $\frac{1}{2^{X}}$.

Based on how I understood your problem.

Comment: Ok, so I think this might work, however, that only calculates the probability for one month. What I really need is the probability that all units will be vacant at the same time at any point in the year.

Also, please change your example to use numbers for the units, because the way I rephrased the question uses letters to represent months Jan = A, Feb = B, Mar = C, etc, and the overlap with your example was initially confusing.

I updated the parameters to clarify that every unit must be vacant for one of the 12 months.